# ssh passphrase works on macOS but fails on AWS Linux. Why?

Tags: linux, ssh, macos

What could cause my SSH passphrase to fail on my AWS VM but work fine on my Mac laptop, for the *exact same keypair*?  See below (blank lines added for clarity).  Passphrase was copy/pasted so is identical, no typos involved.

```bsh
320 ~/.ssh$ uname -a
Darwin mbp.local 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu May  6 00:48:39 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.33~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

321 ~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -y -f md.id_rsa
Enter passphrase:
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDHR9AEY2NOLQBVM5uUAMsKMm2XUXnUoiESGvLTJ7tte86JUI8ZZVDmGxrlP
   [snip]

322 ~/.ssh$ scp md.id_rsa md.id_rsa.pub AWS:.ssh
md.id_rsa                                     100% 2655    44.0KB/s   00:00
md.id_rsa.pub                                 100%  570     9.0KB/s   00:00

323 ~/.ssh$ ssh AWS
Last login: Fri Jul 30 11:56:36 2021 from 10.50.30.167
421 AWS:~$ cd .ssh
422 AWS:~/.ssh$ uname -a
Linux AWS.xyz.com 2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Nov 7 12:42:14 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
423 AWS:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -y -f md.id_rsa
Enter passphrase:
load failed
```

Edited to add, based on comments about versions:
macOS `OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3`
Linux `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`

That's probably the problem, as described by @telcoM in their comment.

So, question is, how to solve it?  Guess I can create a new key-pair on the Linux side..

Comment: What are the versions of ssh-keygen on both systems?  See if there are any incompatibilities there.

Comment: I'm not seeing any easy way to tell.  The man pages (if they can be believed, macOS is horrible about keeping theirs up to date) claim both are OpenSSH 1.2.12.  I was only using `ssh-keygen` as an easy way to test the correctness of my passphrase.  The real problem was an inability to use Git on the AWS host, as it failed to get the SSH key.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of debate on that cross-posting article.  There also seems to be a lot of overlap in topic focus for Superuser and Unix & Linux.  I'll happily delete one if someone can clearly define in which of the 2 the question should be asked.

Comment: `ssh-keygen` normally comes as part of the OpenSSH suite, and `ssh -V` will tell you the version of the SSH client, and thus the entire OpenSSH suite. Although, since the AWS has `.el6` in the version number of its kernel, that indicates it's probably running RHEL/OEL/CentOS 6.x, which is a rather old distribution. I'd bet dollars to donuts that MacOS's OpenSSH is significantly newer and supports some crypto/hash algorithms and that's causing the problem at the AWS side. The man page contains "OpenSSH is a derivative of the original and free ssh 1.2.12..." which can be mistaken for a version.

Comment: @telcoM I think you're right.

Comment: I removed the cross posting, @KamilMaciorowski.

Comment: Since the Mac has the older library, have you tested the reverse to see if the key created on the AWS Linux host can be read on the Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@telcoM's comment above was the correct answer, repeated here for clarity:

> `ssh-keygen` normally comes as part of the OpenSSH suite, and `ssh -V` will tell you the version of the SSH client, and thus the entire OpenSSH suite. Although, since the AWS has .el6 in the version number of its kernel, that indicates it's probably running RHEL/OEL/CentOS 6.x, which is a rather old distribution. I'd bet dollars to donuts that MacOS's OpenSSH is significantly newer and supports some crypto/hash algorithms and that's causing the problem at the AWS side. The man page contains "OpenSSH is a derivative of the original and free ssh 1.2.12..." which can be mistaken for a version. – telcoM Jul 30 at 21:41

Indeed, we are running a quite old version of CentOS 6 in order to support other old software.